# Assign return value to struct member with shorthand assignment/declaration

Tags: go

Why can't I use `:=` when a `struct` member is being assigned one of the return values?

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/OuFOxf_tjF)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct { Bar int64 }

func Baz() (int64, int64) { return 0, 0 }

func main() {
  foo := Foo{}

  var x int64
  x, foo.Bar = Baz() // ok

  y, foo.Bar := Baz() // error

  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", foo)
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
non-name foo.Bar on left side of :=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the spec says so. No, really:

- Short variable declarations are only defined [on identifier lists](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

  `ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .`
- [Identifiers lists](http://golang.org/ref/spec#IdentifierList) do not include [Selectors](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

  `IdentifierList = identifier { "," identifier } .`

Therefore, you are not allowed to assign a selector when using the short variable declaration syntax.

See [this related issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6842) for details. There you can find the reasoning behind this behaviour:

> The := notation is a shorthand for common cases. It's not meant to cover every possible declaration one may write. I'd prefer to leave as is, but won't close this until others have weighed in.